# Python - 'And' operator not functioning properly with dictionary in if function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I seem to be having an issue with the `and` and `in` operator when using dictionaries in Python. I have a dictionary listed with different pieces of clothing inside it, and I have a separate function that deletes these items from the dictionary.

```
clothes = {"socks": 1, "shoes": 2}

def status():
    if "socks" and "shoes" in clothes:
        print("You are wearing socks and shoes.")
    elif "socks" in clothes:
        print("You are wearing only socks.")
    elif "shoes" in clothes:
        print("You are wearing only shoes.")
    else:
        print("You are not wearing socks or shoes.")
```

If I have both the `socks` or `shoes` variable in the clothes dictionary, it will print `You are wearing socks and shoes.`. But if I remove either one, it still fulfills the first `if` function as if both are true, which isn't the case. Only when I remove both do I get a different output, and that jumps to the `else` function.

I am assuming it's an issue with the `in` operator, or I don't properly understand what the `and` operator does, but from reading the documentation it `Returns True if both statements are true`, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

I'm sure there are other ways to go about this, but I'm not quite sure why it doesn't work here. Any clues?

Comment: How do you remove them exactly ? 
did you try  "socks" in clothes and "shoes" in clothes

Comment: @berkayberabi  I used `del clothes["socks"]` and `del clothes["shoes"]`

Comment: "from reading the documentation it Returns True if both statements are true". In your own words, what do you think the two statements are, in the line where you use `and`? Answer: no, they are **not** `"socks" in clothes` and `"shoes" in clothes`. They are `"socks"` and `"shoes" in clothes`. "But if I remove either one, it still fulfills" Not so; it will still pass if you remove the `socks`, but not if you leave the `socks` and remove the `shoes`.

Comment: Also, `if` is not a function, and neither is the expression you write after the word `if`. The term you're looking for is *condition*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `clothes` when you want to check whether any item exists. It does not work if you pass 2 `strings` and then check in a `variable`.  You have to check every `string` in a `variable`.

```
if "socks" in clothes and "shoes" in clothes:
```

The `AND` operator(logical gate) multiply values of 2 things. It will return `True` only if both values are `True`. When you are using a string without checking it exists in a `variable`, it will return `True` because it checks whether the string is `True` - whether it has value.

Comment: I completely forgot about that my mistake, thank you.

Comment: @Elevendy no problem, can you please upvote and accept my answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

In the first line, you forget to check if "socks" are in clothes.

```py
if "socks" in clothes and "shoes" in clothes:
        print("You are wearing socks and shoes.")
```

Comment: Oh, that was a basic mistake thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Due to operator precedence, the statement

```
if "socks" and "shoes" in clothes:
```

is interpreted as if it were

```
if "socks" and ("shoes" in clothes):
```

A non-empty string is always truthy, so this is essentially equivalent to

```
if "shoes" in clothes:
```

Logical operators are not automatically distributed, you need to specify each test and combine them

```
if "socks" in cloths and "shoes" in clothes:
```